# Average formula using number of blank rows above

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on spreadsheet with logged flows that are not at uniform periods.
Looking for formula for Col G that will average values in Col A for logged values for previous 10 minutes.

Here's the spreadsheet data:

```
Flow      Time     min  sec sec  10_min  Average

187.29  06:10:09    10  9   609     
202.90  06:11:21    11  21  681     
280.94  06:12:37    12  37  757     
218.51  06:13:43    13  43  823     
187.29  06:15:13    15  13  913     
124.86  06:16:26    16  26  986     
109.25  06:18:52    18  52  1132        
109.25  06:20:00    20  0   1200     1  177.54

202.90  06:22:30    22  30  1350        
265.33  06:23:36    23  36  1416        
280.94  06:24:42    24  42  1482        
249.73  06:25:58    25  58  1558        
218.51  06:27:39    27  39  1659        
421.41  06:28:47    28  47  1727        
421.41  06:30:00    30  0   1800     1  294.32
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [AVERAGEIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) and construct the criteria with the [TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20D5AC4D-7B94-49FD-BB38-93D29371225C) function while modifying one criteria by ten minutes.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A:A,B:B, TEXT(B9-TIME(0, 10, 0), "\>0.0###############"),B:B, TEXT(B9, "\<\=0.0###############"))
```

[image]

Note that times can also be resolved as decimal numbers which I have used here. My second average came up slightly different from yours. You may wish to change the `\>\=` to `\>` .

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, the average in G9 is correct but when I copy the formula to G16, there are no blank rows in spreadsheet, it gives the value you show but should be 294.32, 21.19 lower then next set are 246.6 instead of actual 227.18?

Comment: There was a floating point conversion error on the 06:30:00 time. I've corrected by increasing the decimal places of the criteria. You could also ROUND() off the times to remove the error.

Comment: Perfect, works great. Added an IF argument so only displays at 10 minutes of the hour mark.

Comment: =IF(F9=1,AVERAGEIFS(A:A,B:B, TEXT(B9-TIME(0, 10, 0), "\>0.0###############"),B:B, TEXT(B9, "\<\=0.0###############")),"")